# Get all files that have been modified in git branch

Tags: git, branch

Is there a way to see what files have changed in a branch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find out which files have been modified in a branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749323/how-can-i-find-out-which-files-have-been-modified-in-a-branch)

Comment: They are not my employees they are my colleagues and it's not them in particular so much as people in general.  But yea, re-reading this post it does seem a bit agro. :)

Comment: Can you use github or bitbucket, gitlab? There are tools to manage exactly this situation. The developer makes a pull request. You get the request and you will have access to a very good interface that will show you a diff of all the changes made to each file. You can even comment, ask for changes etc. When the changes are good you can accept the request which will merge the changes into the requested branch (typically develop). That is the best practice way to handle this situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find out which files have been modified in a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749323/how-can-i-find-out-which-files-have-been-modified-in-a-branch)

Answer (score 262, accepted):

An alternative to the answer by @Marco Ponti, and avoiding the checkout:

```
git diff --name-only <notMainDev> $(git merge-base <notMainDev> <mainDev>)
```

If your particular shell doesn't understand the $() construct, use back-ticks instead.

Comment: ah! this is good fun, now how about if I want to have say <notMainDev> be the current branch I'm on.  that is not have to specify it?

Comment: `git diff --name-only <some-other-branch>` will show you what files are different between your current branch and `<some-other-branch>`. So it's essentially the same command, but note that you can use this to find the files that are different between *any* two branches, even if they're not remotely related. Whether that comparison is useful or not depends on the topology of your branches... Also, note `<some-other-branch>` really could be any commit at all, or anything that resolves to one (tags, etc.).

Comment: hmmm, well, I guess what I mean is that I would like to do  git diff --name-only <notMainDev> $(git merge-base <notMainDev> <MY_CURRENT_CO_BRANCH>)  where MY_CURRENT_CO_BRANCH would of course be my current checked out branch

Comment: You can do that, as well. That will find the point where `<notMainDev>` and `<MY_CURRENT_CO_BRANCH>` most recently had a common ancestor, and compare `<notMainDev>` to that ancestor. You'll have to provide your current branch name, though, as `git merge-base` expects two arguments - there's not a shortcut, at least in the current version.

Comment: ok! I got it.  Courtesy of my colleague what's his name.   git merge-base <notMainDev> `git branch | grep '\*' | awk '{print $2}'`  that will get the commit for the branch between <notMainDev> and my current branch.  I can then do   git diff --name-only <notMainDev> $(git merge-base <notMainDev> `git branch | grep '\*' | awk '{print $2}'`)

Comment: and for the coop-d`etat   [alias] diffbranch =  "!sh -c 'git diff --name-only $1 `git merge-base $1 $(git name-rev HEAD 2> /dev/null | cut -f2)`' -"      !!!

Comment: Nice answer! I'm using Windows was only able to get the `$()` syntax working by using a git bash session - any tips for how I might get it to work in a standard command window (so I can put it in a batch file)?

Comment: Have now worked out how to run a bash command from a batch file - too long to put in a comment so [added an answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641361#41140067).

Comment: Slightly shorter syntax for the current branch: git diff --name-only $(git merge-base master HEAD)...

Comment: This gives the wrong status type for changes. See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: A tip for the uninitiated like me... `git diff --name-only origin/branchX  $(git merge-base origin/branchX origin/master)` vs `git diff --name-only branchX  $(git merge-base branchX master)` which gives  `fatal: Not a valid object name branchX. fatal: ambiguous argument 'branchX': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: for me this did not work. It showed way to many files.. Don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: With Git 2.30 and newer, the above code can be replaced by `git diff --merge-base <notMainDev> --name-only <mainDev>`.

Comment: How to do this on bitbucket?

Comment: Beware `git merge-base` doesn't give the original forking point of the branch, but the closest common ancestor with the other (presumed main) branch. In many cases, both would be identical, but this solution won't work if the branch contains a commit merging main branch into it, in which case it will only list files that have been modified **after** the last merge, but any files modified in the branch before that merge commit (although not merged into main branch yet) won't be listed.

Answer (score 235):

All you have to do is the following:

```
git checkout <notMainDev>
git diff --name-only <mainDev>
```

This will show you only the filenames that are different between the two branches.

Comment: wow quick and too the point.  thank you.  btw I love git.  it's always quick and to the point

Comment: I believe that will also show stuff that has changed on `<mainDev>` since the branches diverged, though. You might want to use `git diff --name-only <sha-of-branch-point>` instead, or see the alternate answer I posted that avoids the checkout.

Comment: Yes, that is true @twalberg it would show those changes if the branches are diverged. I was assuming the `notMainDev` would be kept up to date with the mainDev commits...I usually find it useful to see those differences as well though.

Comment: can't you just specify --right-only to only show the files that were changed on the right side?

Comment: you get the `<sha-of-branch-point>` with `git rev-parse <branch-name>`

Comment: I love this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 124):

amazed this has not been said so far!

```
git diff main...branch
```

So see the changes only on `branch`

To check the current branch use

```
git diff main...
```

Thanks to jqr

This is short hand for

```
git diff $(git merge-base main branch) branch
```

so the merge base (the most recent common commit between the branches) and the branch tip

Also using `origin/main` instead of just master will help in case your local main is dated

Comment: While this shows what has changed, it shows the ALL changes, rather than a summary of the changed files... which is what lead me to this page in the first place :)

Comment: then add the --name-only flag to this. or --short-stat

Comment: `git diff --name-only master..` if you just want the names of files that are different between the two branches.

Comment: This won't work properly if your master had commits after you created your side-branch.

Comment: @simplylizz yes it does. thats exactly what this is solving

Comment: @exussum oh, indeed. Confused three and two dots.

Comment: for me this did not work. It showed way to many files.. Don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: if the repo is public I am happy to take a look, did you use 3 dots ?

Comment: In case any one else pops in here to read comments. This worked perfect for me. I had a `master` branch and a `feature` branch. The `master` branch was way ahead by a bunch of commits. The `feature` branch was behind, but also had `master` merged into it a few times to pull updates. using `git diff --name-status master...feature` gave me exactly what Upsource was showing in the branch review.

Comment: Combined with other answers: `git diff --name-only main...` or, if you have `diffstat`, you could also pipe the result through `diffstat`: `git diff main... | diffstat`.

Comment: This precise syntax actually dumps you into interactive mode, while the OP asked how to get the files.

Comment: I'm guessing what ever your pager is is doing that. This command will just spit out files

Answer (score 80):

I can't believe there are so many ways to do this. I use whatchanged as someone posted before, just with the following arguments:

```
git whatchanged --name-only --pretty="" origin..HEAD
```

This just lists the filenames, and only the ones that changed on the current branch.

Comment: This appears to be the easiest answer here as it requires no additional information. The output looks correct and it's way easier to remember than the accepted answer!

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, more wordy. It provides output fro each commit, in reverse order.
 _git-whatchanged - Show logs with difference each commit introduces_  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged

Comment: From the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged): `New users are encouraged to use git-log instead. The whatchanged command is essentially the same as git-log but defaults to show the raw format diff output and to skip merges.`

Comment: This seems to do what I'm looking for by only printing changes the branch makes alone. It does however print files twice, so I pipe it to `sort -u`

Comment: Yeah, the problem with whatchanged is as @jxramos mentioned: it's actually git log, so it shows things commit by commit. If you've made multiple commits to the same file, you get multiple copies of those names (unlike with git diff).

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: I concur, best answer.

Answer (score 36):

*Update Nov 2020:*

To get the list of files modified (and committed!) in the current branch you can use the shortest console command using standard [git](/questions/tagged/git):

`git diff --name-only master...`

---

- If your local "master" branch is outdated (behind the remote), add a remote name (assuming it is "origin"):

  `git diff --name-only origin/master...`
- If you want to include uncommitted changes as well, remove the `...`:

  `git diff --name-only master`
- If you use different main branch name (eg: "main"), substitute it:

  `git diff --name-only main...`
- If your want to output to stdout (so its copyable):

  `git diff --name-only master... | cat`
- If your want filenames to be clickable in VSCode terminal *no matter what folder you are running this command from*, add `--relative`:

  `git diff --name-only --relative master... | cat`

---

per really nice detailed explanation of different options https://blog.jpalardy.com/posts/git-how-to-find-modified-files-on-a-branch/

Comment: [`diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) has much more options and overall [tag:git-diff] is super awesome ;)

Answer (score 33):

I really liked @twalberg's answer but I didn't want to have to type the current branch name all the time. So I'm using this:

```
git diff --name-only $(git merge-base master HEAD)
```

Comment: Your solution works for me and I get the list of files that I expect to see. I'm a Git novice and have used `git diff master... --name-only` when run on the target branch and get the same result. Could you be so kind as to provide any feedback to what's good vs bad between your answer and the command I've provided?

Comment: Your command will work exactly the same, if master does not have any new commits since your branch was created. I think my command will be equivalent to `git diff master.. --name-only` (note there is only 2 dots instead of 3). To understand what the dots mean, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24186641/1393498)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the quick reply and insight. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 20):

```
git diff --name-only master...branch-name
```

to which we want to compare.

Comment: Seems like a partial of an existing answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41486181/11912

Comment: This variation compares the HEAD of master to a current branch. The accepted answer compares the state of master *at the point you forked*.  Either may have the answer you are looking for, depending on what you want to know.

Answer (score 15):

`git whatchanged` seems to be a good alternative.

Comment: What was exactly that I was looking for.

Comment: From the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged): `New users are encouraged to use git-log instead. The whatchanged command is essentially the same as git-log but defaults to show the raw format diff output and to skip merges.`

Answer (score 8):

What if it could be as easy as this?

```
git changed
```

If you're willing to assume that the main branch is called "master", and that you create your other branches from master, then you can add this alias to your `~/.gitconfig` file to make it that easy:

```
cbranch = !"git branch | grep '*' | cut -f2 -d' '"
changed = !"git diff --name-only $(git cbranch) $(git merge-base $(git cbranch) master)"
```

Those assumptions will work for most people in most situations, but you must be aware that you're making them.

Also, you must use a shell that supports `$()`. [It's very likely that your shell supports this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218065/3358).

Answer (score 4):

For some reason no one mentioned `git-tree`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/1657819

`git-tree` is preferred because it's a *plumbing* command; meant to be programmatic (and, presumably, faster)

(assuming base branch is `master`)

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r master..branch-name
```

However this will show you *all* files which were affected in the branch, if you want to see explicitly **modified** files only, you can use `--diff-filter`:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r master..branch-name --diff-filter=M
```

Also one can use `--name-status` instead of `--name-only` to see the status of the files (`A`/`M`/`D` and so on)

Comment: This was just what I needed for linting changed files while excluding those that were deleted. `rubocop --fail-level error $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r origin/master..HEAD --diff-filter=M)`

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~1
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering you're on a feature branch and you want to check which files have changed compared to master... just this:

```
git diff --name-only master
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git show --stat origin/branch_name
```

This will give you a list of the files that have been added or modified under this branch.

Comment: This is wrong, this only shows the files changed in the head commit of that branch, not the whole branch.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer - `git diff --name-only <notMainDev> $(git merge-base <notMainDev> <mainDev>)` - is very close, but I noticed that it got the status *wrong* for deletions. I added a file in a branch, and yet this command (using `--name-status`) gave the file I deleted "A" status and the file I added "D" status.

I had to use this command instead:

```
git diff --name-only $(git merge-base <notMainDev> <mainDev>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use **grep** so I only get the lines with **diff --git** which are the files path:

```
git diff branchA branchB | grep 'diff --git'
// OUTPUTS ALL FILES WITH CHANGES, SIMPLE HA :)
diff --git a/package-lock.json b/package-lock.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding off of what @twalberg and @iconoclast had, if you're using cmd for whatever reason, you can use:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %x IN (`"git branch | grep '*' | cut -f2 -d' '"`) DO FOR /F "usebackq" %y IN (`"git merge-base %x master"`) DO git diff --name-only %x %y
```

Answer (score 0):

The following batch file is based on twalberg's answer but will work in Windows:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:                               :: <== OR USE A DIFFERENT DRIVE
CD \path\to\where\git\files\are  :: <== CHANGE TO THE ACTUAL PATH
SET /p b="Enter full path of an ALREADY MERGED branch to compare with origin/master: "
bash --login -i -c "git diff --name-only %b% $(git merge-base %b1% origin/drop2/master)"
PAUSE
```

The above assumes that the main branch is origin/master and that git bash was included when Git was installed (and its location is in the path environment). I actually needed to show the actual differences using a configured diff tool (kdiff3) so substituted the following bash command above:

```
bash --login -i -c "git difftool --dir-diff %b% $(git merge-base %b1% origin/drop2/master)"
```