# List all the files between master and current branch int git? It would be great if there is any node package to push out the result in an array :)

Tags: node.js, git, github, command, node-modules

I needed the list of files which are changed in a new from the current local master. Is there any git command to produce the results or any node packages to make the thing simple?

I have tried https://github.com/clakech/committed-git-files which was quite confusing. Can someone suggest me some node packages to do the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all files that have been modified in git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641361/get-all-files-that-have-been-modified-in-git-branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff --name-only XXXXXX master` where XXXXXX is the branch you're comparing against master

Edit:
To get a list of changed files in an array in node

```
const sh = require("run-sh");

sh("git diff --name-only XXXXXX master").then(function(res) {
  const changed = res.stdout.split("\n");
});
```

Comment: The command seems to work well for my case. It would be great if there is a node package to push out the file names in an array :)

Comment: I have this node package: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sh`. You could split the result by newlines if you'd like

Answer (score 1):

From your local branch

```
git diff --name-only master_branch
```