# Git list of common commits between two branches

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-for-windows

We have four branches Branch A, B, C, D.  Branch C is created from Branch A and Branch D is created from Branch B.  We make changes to Branch D and merge them into Branch B. The same changes we cherrypick from Branch D to Branch C and merge into Branch A.

Now we want to list the names and paths of files changed in Branch A because of above behavior.

I have tried my best and now seeking your help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So you start (assuming A and B were created from master) with:

```
           d--d--d
          /
       b--b--b--b--b--b
      /
  m--m
      \
       a--a--a--a
              \
               c--c--c
```

You merge and cherry-pick:

```
           d--d--D
          /       \
       b--b--b--b--b--b
      /
  m--m
      \
       a--a--a--a------------------A
              \                   /
               c--c--c--d'--d'--d'
```

Try first by [listing the files originally modified in branch D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41486181/6309) (with D being the commit just before merging back to A)

```
 git diff --name-only A...D
```

Comment: Hi Von - the problem with this approach is branch A and B are constant. But branch C and D are dynamic. Is there any option to compare the files between A and B and check if they have any common ancestor commit

Comment: @jon `git merge-base A B` would identify the common ancestor

Comment: can we also get the file names ?

Comment: @jon a `git ls-tree -r` of the commit returned by `git merge-base A B` should hep.

Comment: Hi Von- its not working. Is there any way to find the common files changed between branch A and branch B since specific date.

Comment: FYI branch B is created from branch A and my job is to figure out the list of changed files in branch A and the same change should exist in branch B

Comment: @jon Start with https://stackoverflow.com/a/4949604/6309: `git diff --name-status A..B`